# How to unnest nested records in firebase schema?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I am trying to flatten the event level data from firebase analytics but I am unable to unnest nested records. Can anyone please help me out with this?
here is my schema http://take.ms/mjyxw 
here is how I am trying to query the data http://take.ms/w60OY
I am able to unnest the first 2 records but unable to query the third record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third record is not actually an ARRAY (repeated record) but rather STRUCT - so you do not need to UNNEST it. You can access it by referencing it elements as `param.value.string_value` and `param.value.int_value` - assuming param is set as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  dim.name AS event_name,
  param.value.string_value
FROM `your_table`,
UNNEST(event_dim) as dim,
UNNEST(dim.params) as param
WHERE param.value.string_value = 'some value'
```

Comment: I tried the above solution but I am still unable to reference the values like parm.value.string_value etc. Can you please take a look at it http://take.ms/LfeC8

Comment: the query that link is clearly not following my suggestion - rewrite it using notions in my answer!

Comment: I added WHERE clause so you see how to access that field in WHERE clause. Note: it is tested and it works! so you just need carefully adjust your query to follow my example! pay attentions to aliases  i am using to avoid ambiguity in names

Comment: the query did work. One more thing I would like to ask is how can I perform pivot on this column? http://take.ms/3nVXD

Comment: just want to make each value in params.key as a separate column.

Comment: @testedtested - there are quite a number of posts on SO about pivoting in BigQuery. Search and try. If you still will have specific questions  - just post new one :o)